# Maven Module vs Java 9 Module

Tags: java, maven, java-9, jigsaw

Além do fato do Maven trabalhar com jars e o Java 9 com "módulos", qual é a diferença entre o sistema de modularização dos dois?

Por que eu deixaria de modularizar meus sistemas com Maven para modularizar com  Java 9?

Comment: Gostei da pergunta e vou pesquisar uma resposta. Basicamente o maven é o que já existe e o Java 9 é o que veio para organizar as coisas. Mas, ambos são criticados de forma bastante pesada e ambos têm sérias deficiências.

Comment: O Java 9 foi lançado oficialmente hoje e ainda não temos uma resposta a esta pergunta. Para "comemorar" o lançamento, estou dando 100 pontinhos para quem der uma boa resposta a esta pergunta dentro dos próximos 7 dias!

Comment: Eu vi um vídeo do cara do Maven falando disso. Um módulo vai continuar existindo dentro de um jar, então o maven vai importar esse jar. Os módulos se não me engano servem para definir quais partes serão abertas e quais precisam ser recebidas de qual módulo provedor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De um modo bem simples, a diferença é:

- **Maven** gerencia dependências **compile-time**. O Maven facilita a construção do software. Não apenas na hora de compilar, mas também na hora de testar, empacotar e distribuir o software.
- **Java Platform Module System** gerencia dependências **run-time**. Apenas usado em tempo de execução na JVM (máquina virtual Java).

Interessante que até a documentação da classe `Module` ressalta isso. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html

> Represents a run-time module, either named or unnamed.

Resumindo, cada sistema age em momentos diferentes. Não deixe de usar o Maven.

**PERGUNTA BONUS:** Por que eu deixaria de modularizar meus sistemas com **OSGi** para modularizar com Java 9?

**RESPOSTA:** Continue usando OSGi, Java 9 não entende o versionamento dos módulos.

Comment: "*RESPOSTA: Continue usando OSGi, Java 9 não entende o versionamento dos módulos.*" - O porém é que ele veio para ficar, seja por bem ou por mal. Em breve, teremos casos onde os projetos terão que utilizar tanto bibliotecas publicadas no formato de módulos, quanto aquelas no OSGi. E vislumbro que o que vai ocorrer é que as bibliotecas novas saiam nos dois formatos, mas ainda assim muitas bibliotecas antigas demorarão anos para serem atualizadas.

Comment: Passei sexta-feira lendo as release notes do Java 9. Temo que a migração vai complicar a vida de muita gente. Espero que Java 10, ou 18 ou 2018 (porque querem mudar o versionamento do Java) melhore a situação do povo. Mas não podemos esperar muito. :(

Answer (score 2):

## Maven

Os módulos são bibliotecas de código separadas que são adicionados ao projeto como dependência. Como resultado final, temos um projeto composto de diversos módulos que rodam em cima da runtime tradicional do Java (JVM).

## Java 9

Os módulos consistem em partes menores da runtime, específicas conforme a necessidade do projeto. Essa novidade possibilitará uma grande melhoria de desempenho às aplicações, principalmente às que executam em dispositivos com baixo poder de processamento

Comment: Boa, mas foi exatamente isso que quis dizer _Além do fato de um trabalhar com jar e outro com módulo_ :P Acho (quase certeza) que tem muito mais coisa por aí hehe

Answer (score -2):

Este [post](https://dzone.com/articles/java-9-modules-part-2-intellij-and-maven) traz uma consideração importante sobre sua pergunta, e, na minha visão, também a responde:

> "Maven modules are a way to organize your project into several
>   subprojects (modules). With Maven, you can control the versions of
>   these modules and the dependencies between these modules. Each module
>   will produce an artifact. Java modules are a way to strongly
>   encapsulate your classes. It does not provide any means to control the
>   version of an artifact you are using. So, Maven modules and Java
>   modules serve a different purpose. The confusing part is that the same
>   term module is used while they represent something different. But as
>   long as we know the difference, this should not be a problem"

"Módulos no Maven são um meio de organizar seu projeto em subprojetos (módulos). Você pode controlar as versões desses subprojetos bem como as dependências entre eles. Cada subprojetos produzirá um artefato. Módulos em Java são um meio de encapsular fortemente suas classes, eles não proveem quaisquer meios de controlar as versões dos artefatos que sua aplicação usa, **então**, *módulos Maven* e *módulos Java* **servem a propósitos diferentes**. O que pode confundir é o mesmo termo (módulo) ser usado para representar coisas diferentes, mas, sabendo-se distinguir, isso não deve ser um problema"

Comment: Seria interessante postar o trecho traduzido, na sua resposta.

Comment: Boa sugestão @PedroGaspar!